# What is the maximum length of a variable in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I got this warning after adding a long string generated programmatically as an Azure Pipelines variable (as a quick and easy way to test changes instead of pushing a file to my repo):

`##[warning]Environment variable 'INPUT_SCRIPT' exceeds the maximum supported length. Environment variable length: 40384 , Maximum supported length: 32766`

The warning is pretty clear to understand and seems appropriate given a regular environment variable, but the task that used this new pipelines variable works as expected (assuming the entire string is there). Is this warning relevant? Will it bite me in the back later if I just ... leave it in?

Answer (score 7):

The theoretical maximum length of an environment variable is around 32,760 characters. All environment variables must live together in a single environment block, which itself has a limit of 32767 characters.In practice, you have to share the environment block with all the other variables in the block, so your random call to SetEnvironmentVariable with a 32,760-character string is unlikely to succeed.It also depends on how you’re setting the variable; i.e., the code that your environment-variable-setting technique passes through before it gets to the SetEnvironmentVariable call. For details ,please refer to this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=15083).

Here are two cases with the same warning for reference: [1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/317352/vsts-public-variables.html) and [2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/535677/warning-for-vsts-public-variables-during-a-release.html)

> Is this warning relevant? Will it bite me in the back later if I just
> ... leave it in?

For this issue, I have not found the errors caused by this warning. Since you have already paid attention to this issue, if you encounter errors, you can share them here. Let us investigate them further.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some changes to Azure Pipelines as I newly get an error and not a warning anymore. The length of the post script did not change in the last few month.

It says [error] now.

Is there a solution or alternative? Those scripts contain some standard data and also test data cleanup stuff which is deployed with every release (2 week cycle).

```
2023-10-31T12:52:50.4474601Z ##[section]Starting: post_deploy.sql
2023-10-31T12:52:50.4638296Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-31T12:52:50.4638797Z Task         : Azure SQL Database deployment
2023-10-31T12:52:50.4639076Z Description  : Deploy an Azure SQL Database using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD
2023-10-31T12:52:50.4639613Z Version      : 1.225.1
2023-10-31T12:52:50.4639805Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-10-31T12:52:50.4640035Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment
2023-10-31T12:52:50.4640718Z ==============================================================================
2023-10-31T12:52:50.5336552Z ##[warning]Environment variable 'INPUT_SQLINLINE' exceeds the maximum supported length. Environment variable length: 65752 , Maximum supported length: 32766
2023-10-31T12:52:59.6508620Z ##[error]Capacity exceeds maximum capacity.
Parameter name: capacity
2023-10-31T12:52:59.6811966Z ##[section]Finishing: post_deploy.sql
```