# In Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-prem) release pipeline how can one stage pass a file to another stage?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have Azure DevOps Server 2019 on-prem. That means no unified pipelines, no YAML for release pipeline.

The scenario is this:
A stage runs terraform code to provision some resources in Azure. It is necessary to insert manual approval between `terraform plan` and `terraform apply`, however, the plan file produced by `terraform plan` stage must be shared with the `terraform apply` stage.

I can see these options:

1. Save the plan file on a shared file system
2. Save the plan file in a dedicated storage on Azure
3. Save the plan file somewhere within the Azure DevOps so that stages can access it without defining a dedicated file share or Azure storage
4. Pass the contents of the plan file as an output variable

I, personally, like the most the last option, but I wonder what are the limitations on the output variable value length? [What is the maximum length of a variable in Azure Pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534338/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-variable-in-azure-pipelines) suggests it is around 32KB, which may not be good enough. Given that, is there an option to pass files between stages?

Answer (score 0):

There is no default task you can use in classic release pipeline. Due to the limitation of a variable, you would need to publish the file to dedicated file share or Azure storage.

Comment: Does it work in the classic release pipeline? I will check it.

Comment: Task `Publish Build Artifacts` must run in a build to publish artifacts to Azure Pipelines, which means, the plan file needs to be published from a build. I just recheck your query and find I misunderstand your requirement. There is no default task you can use in classic release pipeline. Due to the limitation of a variable, you would need to publish the file to dedicated file share or Azure storage.

Comment: Well that is a disappointment. How long do we need to wait for unified pipeline to become available to those unfortunate who use the on prem version of TFS?

Comment: We don't have the deadline for new features, but I just find an unofficial extension, you may check it to see whether it helps you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.ReleaseArtifacts

Comment: I am not talking about new features. I am talking about the on-prem being a bastard brother of the hosted version. The hosted version has all the goodies, but those who started using TFS before it moved to azure are, paradoxically, punished for their loyalty by not having all the features that hosted has. So, the question is - how long until the goodies already existing in hosted would propagate to the on prem?

Comment: It depends on new release of server, and we don't have an accurate time. You could check the features timeline in following link, which lists significant features delivered to Azure DevOps Services and the corresponding version of Azure DevOps Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline#current-features

Comment: I looked at the page. Features release september 2019 is scheduled to be release to on prem in 2020. That's it. When? Is it march 2020 or december 2020? This is not very helpful.

Comment: I know waiting a new feature release without deadline doesn't feel good. But I don't think there is an accurate time, if there is an accurate time, product team would add it in the documentation. For now, what we can do is waiting for product team's release note. Thanks for your understanding.