# In Azure DevOps release pipeline is it possible to request approval conditionally?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We use Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-prem). I.e. no unified pipelines, no YAML release pipeline.

The scenario is this:

- Stage A invokes `terraform plan` to produce a plan file
- Stage B takes the plan file (somehow, see [In Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-prem) release pipeline how can one stage pass a file to another stage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60250066/in-azure-devops-server-2019-on-prem-release-pipeline-how-can-one-stage-pass-a)) and runs `terraform apply`.
- There is post-deployment approval on Stage A (and/or pre-deployment on Stage B) to let human inspect the plan before applying it.

Now, it does not make sense to request human approval always. We can inspect the plan automatically and request approval only if the plan contains destruction of stateful resources. The scripting code is not a problem, but how to request approval conditionally?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other answer there is not a first class way to do this, but I can suggest a way to get it done using the Rest API and powerShell. It involves a conditional set on an Agentless Job with a manual intervention step.

So release variables can't flow across Agent Jobs or [Stages](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4743) but what you can do is update a release variable, by updating the instance of the release itself via a Rest API call. Then you could use that variable in subsequent Jobs or stages.

In the job where you are getting the Terraform plan output, assuming you are capturing when there is an Add, Change, or Destroy operation you could then marshal that output back into the release, and use it further down the line.

So the example borrows from this post by [Stefan Stranger](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/06/26/PassingVariablesfromStagetoStage/). See also this post by [Donavan Brown](https://www.donovanbrown.com/post/Passing-variables-from-stage-to-stage-in-Azure-DevOps-release).

Assuming the below powerShell script runs in the first Agent phase and has access to your plan result. 
I have predefined a variable in the Release Definition named `TerraformPlanResult`.

```
$releaseurl = ('{0}{1}/_apis/release/releases/{2}?api-version=5.0' -f $($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI), $($env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID), $($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)  )

Write-Host "URL: $releaseurl"
$Release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

#update the predefined $TerraformPlanResult variable
$Release.variables.TerraformPlanResult.value = $YourPlanResult


Write-Output ('Updating Release Definition Instance')
$json = @($Release) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $releaseurl -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" }
```

Now that the `$TerraformPlanResult` variable is available at the release level, you define a Agentless Job with this conditional.

`and(succeeded(), in(variables['TerraformPlanResult'], 'Add', 'Change','Destroy'))`

[image: Conditional Manual Intervention]

Now the [manual intervention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=azure-devops) step will only run if the condition is met.

A couple of other notes:

- You also want to make sure your `Project Collection Build Service` has rights to update release definitions.
- You want to make sure that the first Agent Job has the ability access the OAuth token so you can make the rest calls.

  [image]

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. So, output variables can flow from stage to stage, but not from job to job? That's a bummer.

Comment: Cool I hope it helps! For YAML pipelines you have the option to scope any variable across Jobs, or Stages. For Classic definitions variables are restricted to the scope of the Job. The Rest API is the way to go if you are in that space.  

Here is a link to the output variables section of the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks 

That entire variables topic is recommended reading. It's the most consolidated info for all the different uses based on Classic\YAML.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't such a feature to approve the stages conditionally. I don't think we can achieve that based on current features.

There's already a suggestion ticket submitted here : [Conditional deployment approvals](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/366216/conditional-deployment-approvals.html), you can go and vote it up to help achieve that in future release.

However we can extend the condition by [using approvals and gates to control your deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops), please check it. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: The gate approach suggests I mimic the pre/post deployment logic myself, like fetch email addresses of approvers from somewhere, send emails, present approval GUI, etc... This is not a realistic approach, unless I am missing something. Please, elaborate on that option.

Comment: Yeah, I mean we can combine the approvals and gates, but for your requirements we can not achieve that, request approval conditionally is not supported.