# Do DevOps Pipeline Variables have Size Restrictions and if so, how much?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm more curious about the pipeline variables that can be set at runtime via APIs. Do those have any size limitations?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534338/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-variable-in-azure-pipelines

Comment: Thank you. Should I delete this question since its a duplicate?

Comment: You're welcome! I just closed it :)